# Trouble injecting service into another service (singleton), Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I have two services, both are @Injectable. ServiceA is provided to components via the Providers array and works great everywhere. ServiceB is a singleton and is in the Providers array of its module and works great everywhere. ServiceA needs to remain not a singleton, and ServiceB needs to remain a singleton.

My issue is that now I need to access ServiceA from ServiceB, but don't know how to access it. Seems I cannot inject a non-singleton service into a singleton.

Everything I come across tells me to put the service in bootstrap or module declaration but as I mentioned I cannot do that as I need ServiceA to behave as a non-singleton.

```
// module setup
... providers: [ServiceB]

// non-singleton
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA

// singleton
@Injectable()
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(ServiceA)  // <-- this is the problem area, need to get ServiceA here
```

I have tried doing something like constructor(Inject(ServiceA) serviceA) but seem to get the same errors with that

> Error: DI Error
>   No provider for ServiceA!

1. How can I "provide" a non-singleton service into a singleton service, where both are @Injectable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can declare `ServiceA` both in `@Component.providers` and `@NgModule.providers`:

- When injecting `ServiceA` in a component's constructor, you'll get the component-scoped instance (corresponding to the `@Component.providers` declaration).
- When injecting `ServiceA` in another service's constructor (in your case: when injecting `ServiceA` in `ServiceB`), you'll get the global instance (corresponding to the `@NgModule.providers` declaration).

In other words, if you redeclare a service in a component's providers (`@Component.providers`), it will "shadow" the instance that was declared globally in `@NgModule.providers`.

WORDS OF CAUTION:

- If you inject `ServiceA` into `ServiceB` AND `ServiceC`, then B and C would get the same instance of A.
- As mentioned by Seaal in the comments, organizing the code in this manner might not be aligned with best practices.

Comment: Great thank you @AngularFrance, that does the trick for now. I am mindful of your caution and thought of the same, there must be a way around that though no? I'm thinking it may cause issue down the road... In theory you should be able to inject non-singletons into singletons without causing any issue, shame Angular2 doesn't provide a nice way.

Comment: You're welcome. Another way around the noted limitation might be to restructure your code. I imagine you need your service to be a non-singleton because each service instance must have different state/data. Maybe you could let the service be a singleton while *manually* maintaining a registry for multiple states inside the service. Just thinking out loud, not sure if this is applicable to your situation.

Comment: Injecting non-singletons into singletons is a code smell. You could use the [Angular2 Injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Injector-class.html) directly (ideally within a factory class) if you wish to create different instances of `ServiceA` into multiple other services.

Comment: @Seaal ah cool directly  using the Injector looks like the correct long term solution. As to your code smell comment, I think in this case it's the appropriate setup. Basically I have a data factory that's a singleton which keeps the latest data model from the server accessible to all, and facilitates crud ops via rest. Then I have that non-singleton to manage socket communications and I want to be able to combine its data with the singleton's, and then use it across multiple components (which is why I wanted to do it in the service instead of component)